# Hide Bottom Tabs Navigator Dynamically

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I have a modal.

```
const RenderModal = ({
    modalActive,
}) => {
    return (
        <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={modalActive}
        >
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

I render my modal in my parent view like this;

```
<RenderModal
    modalActive={modalActive}
/>
```

I activate my modal in my parent view like this;

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        setModalActive(true)
    }}
>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

When modal is active, bottom tabs navigator is still visible.

I want to change bottom tabs navigator visibility dynamically.

To achive this I added below to my parent view;

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Then I activate my modal like this;

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false });
        setModalActive(true)
    }}
>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

`navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false })` is not working.

How can I hide my bottom tabs navigator dynamically?

Edit:

Below is not working also.

```
useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible: !modalActive});
}, [modalActive])
```

Comment: This might not be the "React" way of doing things, but these days you can use CSS transitions to dynamically show or hide an element. Personally, I like to do everything that can be done in CSS... in CSS - it's safer and easier to change

Comment: It is React Native :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to change tabbar style.

```
tabBarOptions: {{
 style: {
   height: isShow?140:0,
   overflow: isShow?'visible':'hidden'
 }
}}
```

Comment: How can I pass `isShow` to my navigator?

Comment: you can share states between component by using state management package like redux or useContext. it's working perfectly on my app